# How to setup virtual ip on Linux/Debian

Tags: linux

Hi I am using Debian for MySQL Replication for HighAvailability.I want to set the virtual ip for my two debian machine so that Heartbeat can switch from one machine to another.

I did that by using the command

ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.2 up

but it didnt persist after the reboot.and also I can not give the same ip in both the machine.
How can I assign same virtual IP for both the machine?

Thanks

Comment: The correct term is "alias".

Answer (score 2):

I think that once Heartbeat is configured, it will handle the virtual IP by itself..
See [here](http://johnleach.co.uk/documents/heartbeat/index.html).